# what is the syntax for following excel function in vba

Tags: excel, vba, syntax, formula

```
=CONCATENATE(MID(A3,FIND(" ::",A3)+3,LEN(A3)-8-FIND(" ::",A3)-5),RIGHT(A6,LEN(A6)-8))
```

whats the syntax for this in vba? Would be grateful if anyone point me in right direction.

Comment: What kind of text are your trying to process? Please give an example. Is it always in the same format?

Comment: Try using the record Macro button it will quickly give you the syntax depending on your current cell. It is within the developer tab

Comment: It's more or less the same except you'll need the [Range.Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Just double-up on the double quotes:

```
Sub Sarah()
    MsgBox Evaluate("CONCATENATE(MID(A3,FIND("" ::"",A3)+3,LEN(A3)-8-FIND("" ::"",A3)-5),RIGHT(A6,LEN(A6)-8))")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do it this way, but the answer from Gary's Student should work as well.

```
Sub StackTest()
Dim Result As String
Dim Yoursheet As Worksheet
Dim FirstString As String
Dim SecondString As String

'yoursheet = **enter your worksheet here, then uncomment the line**
FirstString = Yoursheet.Range("A3").Text
SecondString = Yoursheet.Range("A6").Text

Result = Mid(FirstString, InStr(FirstString, " ::") + 3, Len(FirstString) - 8 - _
    InStr(FirstString, " ::") - 5) & Right(SecondString, Len(SecondString) - 8)

End Sub
```